# How to decode json string?

Tags: php, json

I am working on one project. In which I am getting data in json string format from android or iOs application. I am using json decode to decode it. But I didnt get any array.

ioS and Android calls following URL and pass data in REQUEST mode through URL. Url is as follows :

```
http://dummy.test.pro/webservices/Cart/AddToCartMatrix?{ "Add_Cart" = "{\n \"product_id\" : \"30\",\n \"user_id\" : \"67\",\n \"design_inventory\" : \"design_master\",\n \"table\" : \"temp_cart\"\n}"; }
```

In PHP, I am reading data as follows :

```
$cart_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['Add_Cart']));
pre($cart_data);
```

But After calling URL , I am getting following error :

Message: Undefined index: Add_Cart

Please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means that *Add_Cart* isn't an index in your *$_REQUEST* array.

why don't you use something like `print_r($_REQUEST)` to check the content of your request?

Comment: If I am writing print_r($_REQUEST) then I am getting data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain of how you are sending the request but handling the request but I think changing how you send your request uri from.

```
http://dummy.test.pro/webservices/Cart/AddToCartMatrix?{ "Add_Cart" = "{\n \"product_id\" : \"30\",\n \"user_id\" : \"67\",\n \"design_inventory\" : \"design_master\",\n \"table\" : \"temp_cart\"\n}"; }
```

to:

```
http://dummy.test.pro/webservices/Cart/AddToCartMatrix?Add_Cart=%7B%5Cn+%5C%22product_id%5C%22+%3A+%5C%2230%5C%22%2C%5Cn+%5C%22user_id%5C%22+%3A+%5C%2267%5C%22%2C%5Cn+%5C%22design_inventory%5C%22+%3A+%5C%22design_master%5C%22%2C%5Cn+%5C%22table%5C%22+%3A+%5C%22temp_cart%5C%22%5Cn%7D
```

Read more about why this may work [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

[image: works]
[image]

In my own tests this method works. Ensure that you call some URL encoding function for the JSON and make Add_Cart as the variable name of the json. (not wrapping it in JSON as it)

Answer (score 0):

This iOS/Android app is sending a pretty malformed URL which does not use any known or valid query string format. That means that you cannot rely on PHP to decode it for you into `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.

Unless you can contact the app creators to get it fixed, you'll have to fetch the raw data from the URL (if GET):

```
$json = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

... or the request body (if POST):

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

However, it's still possible (I'd say likely) that data has got corrupted on transport and further `json_decode()`fails. If so, you'll need additional string replacements to try and get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
http://dummy.test.pro/webservices/Cart/AddToCartMatrix?Add_Cart={\n \"product_id\" : \"30\",\n \"user_id\" : \"67\",\n \"design_inventory\" : \"design_master\",\n \"table\" : \"temp_cart\"\n}
```

you might missed get method key